# r.js loading error when trying to optimise

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, r.js

I have the following in my main.js file:

```
/*--- Require.js: the main module loader ---*/
require.config({ 

    baseUrl: '/javascripts/libs/home/', 
    waitSeconds: 0,    
    paths   : { 
        jquery                  : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min', 
        jqueryui                : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min', 
        underscore              : '/javascripts/libs/vendor/underscore/underscore-min', 
        backbone                : 'vendor/backbone/backbone.min', 
        marionette              : 'vendor/backbone.marionette/backbone.marionette.min', 
        tpl                     : 'vendor/require/tpl', 
        moment                  : 'vendor/moment/moment', 
        datetimepicker          : 'vendor/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.min', 
        tipso                   : 'vendor/tipso/tipso.min' 
    }, 

    shim    : {
        underscore: { 
          exports: '_' 
        }, 
        backbone: { 
            deps        : ['jquery', 'underscore'], 
            exports     : 'Backbone' 
        }, 
        marionette: { 
            deps        : ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], 
            exports     : 'Marionette' 
        }, 

        datetimepicker: {
            deps        : ['jquery', 'jqueryui'], 
            exports     : 'Datetimepicker' 
        }, 

        tipso: {
            deps        : ['jquery'], 
            exports     : 'Tipso' 
        }
    }, 
    config: {
        moment: {
            noGlobal: false
        }
    }
}); 

//--- Define Google maps to make it globally accessible throughout the application ---// 
define('gmaps', ['require_async!https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry,places&key=AIzaSyDRKg-SNBODA1mKMCRrfMrls48x7owr9w8&sensor=true"'],
function(){
    // return the gmaps namespace for brevity
    return window.google.maps;
}); 

// --- Initialize the application ---// 
require(["zwoop"], function(Zwoop){ 
    Zwoop.start(); 
});
```

When trying to optimize the file with r.js, I get the following error:

> Error: Tried loading "zwoop" at /javascripts/libs/home/zwoop.js then
>   tried node's require("zwoop") and it failed with error: Error: Cannot
>   find module 'zwoop'
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2562:27
>       at Object.context.execCb (/usr/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1921:33)
>       at Object.Module.check (/usr/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1125:51)
>       at Object.Module.enable (/usr/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1412:22)
>       at Object.Module.init (/usr/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1033:26)
>       at callGetModule (/usr/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1439:63)
>       at Object.context.completeLoad (/usr/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1815:21)
>       at Function.req.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2575:17)
>       at Object.context.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1910:21)
>       at Object.Module.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1079:29)

"Zwoop" is just a require module that loads my app. It runs correctly without the optimisation and the path is clearly correct.

Any idea what my cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define the path of a dependency into the `paths` config it will look for the dependency into the `baseUrl` directory.
So either there's no `swoop.js` file into your `baseUrl` directory either it's not defined as a proper module : `define([...], function(...){ ... })`